# Node js http : url not match to request

Tags: node.js, http, url

I have created a server with node js but I have a big mistake.
I use the library HTTP for receive request from port 3000 I try to get the URL of the request.
So I try localhost:3000/dashboard and I perfectly read /dashboard
Now I try localhost:3000/data and I receive /
WHY ?

here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', function(req,res){
    console.log('CALL : '+req.url);
res.end();
});
server.listen(3000);`
```

thanks for help me

Comment: If you navigate to `localhost:3000` in browser you'll get `/` for `req.url` otherwise you should get the full url after `localhost:3000`. May be you get `/` for req.url because you do not notice that you some how navigate to `localhost:3000`

Comment: Can you open browser's DevTool, then open `localhost:3000/dashboard` and take a screenshot of what DevTool's Network panel tells?